# Timestamp with time zone, unknown using django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

After shifting from MariaDB to postgres-10 i am getting below error
I am using Django-orm

> > function date_format(timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist 
> >     LINE 1: SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%h %p')) AS "in_hours", SUM(...
> >
> > > HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
Model.objects.filter(franchise=franchise)\
             .filter(created_at__date=date)\
             .extra(select={'in_hours': "DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%%h %%p')"}) \
             .values('in_hours')\
             .order_by('created_at__hour')\
             .annotate(total_amount=Sum('amount'))
```

Can anyone please explain where its going wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no DATE_FORMAT function in Postgres, you must use TO_CHAR https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html